# How can I authenticate against Azure AD from a browser in a non-interactive workflow?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a website hosted as Azure App Service with Azure Active Directory authentication enabled. Users can sign in from their browser using the interactive workflow.

The website must run as a dashboard on a big screen 24/7. There it is not possible to use the interactive workflow for authentication there, since there is no user to enter credentials.

How can I achieve this?

Is it possible to use a service principle with a client certificate? If so: How?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client credential flow to obtain a token to call the Web API hosted in your App Service on your behalf (not on behalf of the user). This solution is useful for non-interactive daemon applications that perform tasks without logged in users.

Since you have enabled Azure AD authentication in the app service, you only need to register the daemon app in the Azure portal. When you use the  [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) to request the application hosted by the APP service, Just replace `resource` with the application ID URL hosted by APP service.

please see:[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#register).

Comment: Thanks, but I think this workflow is not possible from within a browser. You can only use it to authenticate a client application.